# strcat causing segmentation fault in a loop

Tags: c, loops, segmentation-fault

I am running a program in a virtual machine. I'm executing a loop in which, at some point, I call strcat. After a number (this number changes between different executions) of loops I receive segmentation fault.

I tried to debug it:

```
(gdb) backtrace

0  0x001a3d5d in strcat () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6

1  0x080493f4 in ChangetoDnsNameFormat (dns=0xbffef313 "", 
    host=0xbffff3b8 "a.com", '.' <repeats 195 times>...) at my_dns.c:378

2  0x08048c96 in nreplacehost (
    host=0xbffff3b8 "a.com", '.' <repeats 195 times>..., query_type=1, 
    ip=0xbffff354 "3.3.3.3") at my_dns.c:179

3  0x080489a1 in main (argc=774778414, argv=0xbffff4d4) at my_dns.c:106

(gdb) frame 1

1  0x080493f4 in ChangetoDnsNameFormat (dns=0xbffef313 "", 
    host=0xbffff3b8 "a.com", '.' <repeats 195 times>...) at my_dns.c:378
378     strcat((char*)host,".");

(gdb) print host

6 = (unsigned char *) 0xbffff3b8 "a.com", '.' <repeats 195 times>...
```

Any tips?

This is the function in which I call strcat

```
void ChangetoDnsNameFormat(unsigned char* dns,unsigned char* host) 
{
    int lock = 0 , i;
    strcat((char*)host,".");

    for(i = 0 ; i < strlen((char*)host) ; i++) 
    {
        if(host[i]=='.') 
        {
            *dns++ = i-lock;
            for(;lock<i;lock++) 
            {
                *dns++=host[lock];
            }
            lock++; //or lock=i+1;
        }
    }
    *dns++='\0';
}
```

This function is called successfully for more than 1000 times.

Comment: Can we see ChangetoDnsNameFormat ? It might help

Comment: What normally goes wrong in these cases, is that you write past the end of the data structure. The first couple of times you are lucky, that memory after that structure is still in your address space, but then at some point you write beyond the address space of the process itself, and that is when the kernel knocks you out with a SIGSEGV.

Comment: How much space have you allocated for `host`?

Comment: @sapi: let me guess: 200 bytes.

Comment: @wildplasser it looks like it in the backtrace but if that's the case, that wouldn't explain the segfault. Do the terminating `null` character should appear in gdb ?

Comment: IMO the <repeats 195 times> just counts up to the NUL. And the NUL will probably have overwritten the argv guardpage (which is about 0x120 bytes above the dns[] buffer). So the buffer would at least be 280 bytes.

Comment: Wait, it seems you also write stuff to the *dns pointer, and the amount you write to that depends on the length of the host string? So the issue could also be that you write beyond the end of *dns. I think it is customary, in cases where you pass pointers to structures of variable length, to also pass an integer argument specifying the length, and then to ensure inside your code that you stay under it. Look at things like strncat, strncpy, snprintf, all the "n" variants.

Comment: It appears this terrible code is from the dreaded WinSock: http://www.binarytides.com/dns-query-code-in-c-with-winsock/

Comment: Yes, this is not my code, I only modified it a little to test something. Aaand I realized there is no need and a waste of time to call that function in the loop so I took it out and now my loop finishes successfully. But it would be nice to know what the problem was. And thank you all for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char * strcat ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

When you call `strcat`, the `source` will be appended to the `destination` string (the terminating null character of `destination` will be replaced by the first character of `source` and so on). **`destination` must have enough allocated space** to contain the concatenated string. Also note that both **`source` and `destination` must be null-terminated strings**.

*Regarding your code*

```
void ChangetoDnsNameFormat(unsigned char* dns,unsigned char* host) {
    strcat((char*)host,".")
```

Since you are using the parameter `host` to store the concatenated string, you must ensure before calling `ChangetoDnsNameFormat` that `host` is a [null-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) and contains enough allocated memory to store the extra `.`.

Keep in mind that `strcat((char*)host,".")` is equivalent to :

```
host[strlen((char*)host)] = '.';
host[strlen((char*)host)+1] = '\0';
```

That makes the need for a large enough, null-terminated string quite explicit.

Your *backtrace* suggests that you are either calling `ChangetoDnsNameFormat` without allocating the space needed by your trailing dot or you're missing the terminating null character in `host` or `dns` .

Writing to an unallocated memory location is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) so it may or may not crash immediately. It's not surprising if it works 1000 times and cause a segfault at the 1001st time

Comment: Even worse: "a.com" is a *string-constant*, which is not writable at all.

Comment: @wildplasser yes that was not the most relevant example

Comment: The host is defined as unsigned char[200] and is scanf-ed, so I suppose there is no problem problem with it and dns is an unsigned char * assigned like this: dns = (unsigned char*)&buf[sizeof(struct DNS_HEADER)], where buf is an unsigned char[65536]. I don't see where memory issue would be.

Comment: @user2333227 So the `strcat` is fine as long as the host length is less than 198 characters. There must have been some memory corruption before the call to to `strcat` that causes the *segfault*. There are so much potentially undefined behaviors in this code that it's really hard to tell where the problem actually is without knowing about the entire program.

Answer (score 1):

Strcat() appends to the end of a string. If you keep calling it, without checking whether there's room for the material you are adding, you will eventually run off the end of the string. Run far enough off the end of the string, and you'll probably come to the end of your process' address space; the operating system will then send you a SIGSEGV.

By the looks of the above gdb trace, you are adding "." repeatedly until this happens. You don't show enough code for me to determine what kind of coding error got you to this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep appending to the end of the string, you will exceed the size of the buffer, and thus may cause segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

More importantly, you do not seem to need `strcat()` at all. Just change `strlen((char*)host)` to `strlen((char*)host) + 1` (or calculate once and store in a local variable, as C `strlen` needs to iterate over the whole string) and change the if-condition to

```
if(host[i]=='.' || host[i]=='\0')
```

to treat the end of the string like the dot you now no longer need to append.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_change( char* dns, char* host);
void hexdump(char *src, size_t len);

  /* function which does exactly the same as
  ** ChangetoDnsNameFormat() but without strcat()
  ** or enormous amounts of strlen() calls
  ** the caller should take care that
  ** *) dns is at least one byte larger than host
  ** *) host is properly terminated.
  */
void my_change( char *dns, char *host)
{
unsigned char *dst = (unsigned char*) dns
        , *src = (unsigned char*) host
        , *tick;

for (tick=dst++;  *dst = *src++; dst++) {
        if (*dst == '.') { *tick = (dst-tick-1); tick = dst; }
        }
*tick = (dst-tick-1);
}

void hexdump(char *src, size_t len)
{
size_t idx;
for (idx =0; idx < len; idx++) {
        fprintf(stderr, " %2x", src[idx] % 0xff );
        }
fputc( '\n', stderr);
}


/* And test it ... */

int main (void)
{

char source[] = "www.stackoverflow.com";
char target[1+sizeof source] = "";

my_change( target, source);

printf("Source:%s\n", source);
hexdump(source, strlen(source) );

printf("Myname:%s\n", target);
hexdump(target, strlen(target) );

return 0;
}
```